# How to remove unmounted component from the heap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, garbage-collection

I have a reactJS app and it keeps falling saying
 `FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

I tried to look at the google chrome heap Snapshot and i found out that unmounted components are still in the heap. How can i remove them? I guess there is some object that links to them but i have no idea how to know which one.

Comment: Are you using refs ?

Comment: @kemicofa i do in some component but i see all the components in the heap weather they have refs or not. (I rarely use refs)

Comment: Can you provide an example of a component that is still mounted and where exactly you use that component ?

Comment: I render a lot of cards when entering the “cards” tab. But when i move to another tab the “Card” component didn’t get garbage collected

Comment: Are you using react-router or react-navigation?

Comment: I’m using react-router